# Is there a way I restrict AWS CloudFront distribution for a region only to save costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I don't want my AWS CloudFront distribution to be spread across the world given that i know my target customer geography. I don't care of the rest of the world beyond this geographic region. This helps me to save unwarranted data transfer costs to the rest of the regions.

FYI, the [AWS Doc on Getting Started with a Simple CloudFront Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.SimpleDistribution.html#GettingStartedCreateDistribution)doesn't show an option for this.

Did I miss anything? Is this possible?

Would really appreciate your inputs. Thanks!

Comment: CloudFront does not charge for data transfer "to the rest of the regions."  There is no charge for data transfer from S3 or EC2 to CloudFront, and no data is transferred to any CloudFront edge unless the content is first requested by a viewer near that edge.  It seems possible that you are trying to avoid something that already doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot instruct cloudfront to store content on a particular region. but you can use price classes to limit cloudfront to fetch content from particular location. The locations are not region.

Look at cloudfront pricing, 
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

But if you need to prevent users in specific countries from accessing your content, you can use the CloudFront geo restriction feature:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.SimpleDistribution.html#GettingStartedCreateDistribution

Comment: having said that, you can make use of cloudfront's geo restriction feature to whitelist only users from a particular country. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html